# How to push back a vector recursively?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to push all permutation results into a vector; for example, if initial x = 4 and y = 4, I would like to push 4C4, 4C3, 4C2, 4C1 and 4C0 into my vector. Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
std::vector<int> generateVector(int x, int y){
    std::vector<int> v;
    if(y < 0){
        return v;
    }
    v.push_back(permutation(x, y));
    --y;
    generateVector(x, y);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, each time `generateVector` is called the function creates its own local variable `std::vector<int> v;` and either returns it immediately or pushes something into it and returns that. The value returned by the recursive call to `generateVector` is ignored.

Comment: @Fnr -- yes, but that's not all there is to it. That would return the value generated by the recursive call, but that value doesn't include the value that's pushed back into `v`.

Comment: @Nav The OP asked "_Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code?_" which implies it has [code that doesn't work as intended](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650/120114) thus it is not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR. Please refrain from suggesting users post there unless the posts would be on-topic there. For more information, see [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114).

Answer (score 0):

You're not capturing the return value for the recursive call. Set it to a variable, then copy into v. That being said, there are better ways to solve this problem than recursion.